# What is the best practice to design the rest api url if one resource identifier is a path

Tags: rest

It is straightforward to put resource id into url if it is a int or long type. e.g.

```
GET files/123
```

But my problem is that my resource identifier is a path. e.g. `/folder_1/folder_2/a.sh` because the underlying implementation is a filesystem. So I can not put it as part of rest api url because it is conflict with url path.

Here's approaches what I can think of:

1. Put the path id as the request param. e.g.
   `GET files?path=/folder_1/folder_2/a.sh`
2. Encode/decode the path to make it qualifier as part of url.
3. Introduce another int/long id for this resource in backend. And map it to the path. The int/long type resource id is stored in database. And I need to maintain the mapping for each CURD operation.

I am not sure whether approach 1 is restful, approach 2 needs extra encoding/decoding, and approach 3 needs extra work to maintain the mapping.

I wonder what is the best practice to design the rest api url for this kind of case.

Comment: Before suggesting any solution, cal you first clarify the requirements specs of what you are trying to achieve? that will let me explain more about any better implementation and design detail

Comment: @auvipy I added more context, let me know if you need more, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
@GET
@Path("/files/{path:.+}")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String files(
        @PathParam("path") String path
) {
    return path;
}
```

When you query `files/test1/tes2` via url output is:

```
test1/tes2
```

Comment: I think we should use `{*path}` according the doc here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html

Comment: Which you say is `.*` regex meaning `zeroOrMoreCharacter`, so if someone query just with /files/ without any more it can accept and try to find a file which name is blank, but via `.+` regex this will accept `oneOrMore` character

Comment: I tried `{path:.+}`, but it only match one layer

Comment: again I tested, its working also via:  `files/test1/test2/test3/asdf-78.+.qwer`

Answer (score 1):

Just put the path after a prefix, for example:

```
GET /files/folder_1/folder_2/a.sh
```

There isn't a conflict, since when the request path starts with your known prefix (`/files/`, in the above example), you know that the rest should be parsed as the path to the file, including any slashes.

Comment: This won't work if I want to introduce actions on the resources. e.g.

Comment: e.g. 
PUT /files/folder_1/actions/a.sh/actions/run.  I am not sure whether backend (spring boot) can parse this kind of url correctly.

Comment: You could consider putting putting the known part in front of the path, e.g. `/actions/run/folder_1/folder_2/a.sh` to minimize problems when parsing the path.

Comment: Alternatively, you could do consider triggering "actions" by doing a `POST /files/folder_1/folder_2/a.sh` and specifying the action to run in the POST request, for example in a query parameter or the request body.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my experience designing "restful" APIs shows that you have to take into consideration future extensions of your API.

So, the guidelines work best when followed closely *when it makes sense*.

In your specific example, the path of the file is more of an attribute of the file, that can also serve as its unique ID.
From your API client's perspective, `/files/123` would make perfect sense, but `/files/dir1/file2.txt` is debatable.

A query parameter here would probably help more, much like what you would do if you wanted to retrieve a *filtered* list of files, rather than the whole collection.

On the other hand, using a query parameter would also help for future extensions, since supporting `/files/{path}` would also mean conflicts when attempting to add sub-resources to your files endpoint.

For example, let's assume that you might need in the future another endpoint `/files/attributes`. But, having such an endpoint, would exclude any possibility for your clients to match a file named `attributes`.

Comment: The problem of `/files/123` is that I have to introduce 123 in backend as its id (and maintain the mapping between this id and path). The only  purpose of this id is just for as part of rest url, not needed by my business logic as I can use path as its unique id.

Comment: Exactly, this is why I didn't propose it in the solution. Introducing specific IDs would create extra development/maintenance effort for both the server and the clients, for the shake of guidelines only, which beats the purpose.